# UITableView + UITextField + UIDatePicker

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have `UIViewController` and `UITableViewCell` with `UITextField` and `UIDatePicker`. If I change the value in the first cell `UITextField` I change the value in cell 1 and 7. If I change the value in the second cell `UITextField` I change the value in cell 2 and 8. And after the scroll value from the first cell sometimes moves in a second. Why is this happening? For cell I created a separate class which is `UITextField` and `UIDatePicker`.

My `UIViewController`

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
     return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
     return [self.stepsController.timeadayVal integerValue];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    addCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    cell.titleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i прием",indexPath.row+1];

    return cell;
}
```

**UITableViewCell.m**

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
if (self) {

    _titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 10, 320, 20)];

    _titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:17];
    _titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];

    [self addSubview:_titleLabel];

    _textField = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 35, 280, 35)];

    UIView *paddingView6 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 20)];
    _textField.leftView = paddingView6;
    _textField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;

    [_textField.layer setBackgroundColor: [[UIColor colorWithRed:249.0/255.0 green:249.0/255.0 blue:249.0/255.0 alpha:1] CGColor]];
    [_textField.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor colorWithRed:245.0/255.0 green:246.0/255.0 blue:247.0/255.0 alpha:1] CGColor]];
    [_textField.layer setBorderWidth: 0.2];
    [_textField.layer setCornerRadius:3.0f];
    [_textField.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];

    _textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"00:00"];
    _textField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:16.0];
    _textField.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];


    UIToolbar *myToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    NSMutableArray *itemsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    UIBarButtonItem *flexButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
    [itemsArray addObject:flexButton];
    UIBarButtonItem *doneButton =
    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone
                                                  target:self action:@selector(inputAccessoryViewDidFinish:)];

    [doneButton setTitleTextAttributes:@{
                                         UITextAttributeFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Light" size:15.0],
                                         UITextAttributeTextColor: [UIColor colorWithRed:60.0/255.0 green:162.0/255.0 blue:161.0/255.0 alpha:1]
                                         } forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [itemsArray addObject:doneButton];
    [myToolbar setItems:itemsArray animated:NO];


    UIDatePicker *timePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
    timePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeTime;

    [timePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(timeChanged:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    _textField.inputAccessoryView = myToolbar;
    _textField.inputView = timePicker;

    _textField.inputView = timePicker;

    [self addSubview:_textField];
}
return self;
}


-(void)timeChanged:(id)sender{

    UIDatePicker *picker=(UIDatePicker*)_textField.inputView;
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"HH:mm"];
    NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:picker.date];

    _textField.text = dateString;

}

-(void)inputAccessoryViewDidFinish:(id)sender {

    [_textField resignFirstResponder];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Secondly, the thing with the display bugs of the textfield is a structure problem. Check ur structure and keep in mind that evertime u scroll the cells are loading new. and if you add subviews all the time its just a mess u got like 4 views of the same textfield ans so on...... be sure that there is only just one at all time.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a cell reuse problem. When you call `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` you may get a cell which has already been used. When this happens you need to clean out all of the old information. Currently you only set the title label text. But you also need to configure your text field and date picker (to default or saved values for the index path).

Answer (score 0):

Please write a couple of code.
Anyway i think the best practice for you is to create UIViewController, then uiview instead of uitableviewcell, then in uiview add uitextfield and date picker, because cells are for uitableview.
Also i don't understand how much cells you have, mb better to create uitableview with cells instead of uiviewcontroller.
Your bug in your code, please post him in update. Look at the tags and how you migrate your data. so update please.

Answer (score 0):

OK, first you are mixing up some expressions in wrong context. 
I think i understood ur problem.

The reason for this is that if you scroll and the cell scrolls out of the screen and then you scroll back it loads again the cell-Method. So the value you changed isn't saved in this method so it calles the old value again.

Maybe you should store your changed values in temp-variables and in the method that calls the cell just do an if.

```
if(value != tmpValue && tmpValue != 0) 
{
   value = tmpValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
addCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

This function does not guarantee to return a cell, it returns any that are available to be reused, but it looks like your not setting a reuse identifier anywhere. If you use storyboards to create the layout of the cell and then refer to its cellIdentifer it will be returned by this call. However outside of that you have to create the cell and set its identifier. I would imagine you are getting some unexpected logic because of this.

Don't store a global reference to the cell either and check if the dequeue function returns nil. Like so:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *addCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if(addCell == nil)
{
     addCell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle: <style> reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier ];
}

...
...
```

It looks / sounds like your using the same cell instance in multiple locations. When one changes they all change when the cell's are refreshed. The purpose of the dequeue function is to return an new instance based off an already complied / create cell object. They need to all be separate instances.

Comment: The same thing happens.

Comment: @Alexey you've placed all the above code inside the cellForRowAtIndexPath callback and you no longer have a global reference ?

Comment: if I bring the value of all cells in the nslog I mean 0,1,2,3 cell is nill. If I change the value in the first cell 0,1,2,3 ostayustya nill and 6 cell changes.

Comment: @Alexey I don't understand what your saying. If you change the value of one cell and this causes all of them to change, this is showing you that the tableview is pointing to the same cell instance for each of its rows. When the value of one of these instances changes they all change when the rows are updated. You need to ensure that each cell object you have is its own separate variable. Did you use exactly the code I provided inside the cellForRowAtIndexPath callback, in particular where I use 'UITableViewCell *addCell' for each loop ???

Comment: Yes exactly. But the same thing happens.